# Pandas merge dataframes with shared column, fillna in left with right

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes and replace the nan in the left df with the right df, I can do it with three lines of code as below, but I want to know if there is a better/shorter way?

```
# Example data (my actual df is ~500k rows x 11 cols)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [0,1,np.nan, 1], 'e': ['a', 1, 2,'b']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [np.nan, 1, 0, 1]})

# Merge the dataframes...
df = df1.merge(df2, on='a', how='left')

# Fillna in 'b' column of left df with right df...
df['b'] = df['b_x'].fillna(df['b_y'])

# Drop the columns no longer needed
df = df.drop(['b_x', 'b_y'], axis=1)
```

### Update 2023

For not nan but still similar update

```
df1 = df1.set_index('a')
df2 = df2.set_index('a')
df1.update(df2)
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: I rephrased your question to state the desired behavior: "Fillna in 'b' column of left df with right df". Really you want to skip the left-merge giving you two unwanted columns 'b_x, b_y' in the first place, then having to manipulate them. That's what [`update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html#pandas.DataFrame.update) is for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem confusing merge is that **both dataframes have a 'b' column, but the left and right versions have NaNs in mismatched places. You want to avoid getting unwanted multiple 'b' columns 'b_x', 'b_y' from `merge` in the first place**:

- slice the non-shared columns 'a','e' from df1
- do `merge(df2, 'left')`, this will pick up 'b' from the right dataframe (since it only exists in the right df)
- finally do [`df1.update(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html#pandas.DataFrame.update) , this will update the NaNs in the column 'b' taken from df2 with `df1['b']`

Solution:

```
df1.update(df1[['a', 'e']].merge(df2, 'left'))

df1

   a    b  e
0  1  0.0  a
1  2  1.0  1
2  3  0.0  2
3  4  1.0  b
```

**Note:**  Because I used `merge(..., how='left')`, I preserve the row order of the calling dataframe. If my `df1` had values of `a` that were not in order

```
   a    b  e
0  1  0.0  a
1  2  1.0  1
2  4  1.0  b
3  3  NaN  2
```

The result would be

```
df1.update(df1[['a', 'e']].merge(df2, 'left'))

df1

   a    b  e
0  1  0.0  a
1  2  1.0  1
2  4  1.0  b
3  3  0.0  2
```

Which is as expected.

---

#### Further...

If you want to be more explicit when there may be more columns involved

```
df1.update(df1.drop('b', 1).merge(df2, 'left', 'a'))
```

#### Even Further...

If you don't want to `update` the dataframe, we can use `combine_first`

**Quick**

```
df1.combine_first(df1[['a', 'e']].merge(df2, 'left'))
```

**Explicit**

```
df1.combine_first(df1.drop('b', 1).merge(df2, 'left', 'a'))
```

---

#### EVEN FURTHER!...

The `'left'` `merge` may preserve order but **NOT** the index.  This is the ultra conservative approach:

```
df3 = df1.drop('b', 1).merge(df2, 'left', on='a').set_index(df1.index)
df1.combine_first(df3)
```

Comment: `update` function doesn't work for me; however the `combine_first` did exactly what I wanted, thank you

Comment: kslookall: `update` works fine, please retry in a clean session with pandas 0.24, and confirm it works.

Comment: @piRSquared you really need to explain that [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html#pandas.DataFrame.update) is filling the NAs, before the left-merge, so they don't cause unwanted multiple 'b' columns 'b_x', 'b_y'.

Comment: That’s fair. I’ll add explanation when I have a chance

Comment: I edited in some explanation. It's confusing that you present so many alternatives, please edit concise one-line explanations of when you need each one.

Comment: The comment *"The 'left' merge may preserve order but NOT the index."* seems irrelevant and confusing, clearly both dfs have a shared column `a` that can be used to `merge(..., on='a')`, so their indexes are irrelevant, and good solutions shouldn't rely on it. It's better to explain why something is a solution, rather than worry the user by discussing lots of possible problems.

Comment: I disagree with the last bit. People using merge might not be aware that it blows up the index and they might’ve cared about it. OP never states one way or the other but I implicitly decide for them with an answer that disregards the index. I’m not perfectly consistent but my answers tend to addressing the details of the data, index, and column elements of a dataframe

Comment: Your code for `update` also did not work for me (four years later). But `combine_first` did.

Answer (score 6):

The data

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [0,1,np.nan, 1], 'e': ['a', 1, 2,'b']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [np.nan, 1, 0, 1]})
```

Short version

```
df1.b.fillna(df1.a.map(df2.set_index('a').b),inplace=True)
df1
Out[173]: 
   a    b  e
0  1  0.0  a
1  2  1.0  1
2  3  0.0  2
3  4  1.0  b
```

Since you mentioned there will be multiple columns

```
df = df1.combine_first(df1[['a']].merge(df2, on='a', how='left'))
df
Out[184]: 
   a    b  e
0  1  0.0  a
1  2  1.0  1
2  3  0.0  2
3  4  1.0  b
```

Also we can pass to `fillna` with df

```
df1.fillna(df1[['a']].merge(df2, on='a', how='left'))
Out[185]: 
   a    b  e
0  1  0.0  a
1  2  1.0  1
2  3  0.0  2
3  4  1.0  b
```

Comment: Operating on the dataframe `df1` without any inplace mutation... If you wanted to: `df1.fillna({'b': df1.a.map(df2.set_index('a').b)})`

Comment: If you look good, this can be variant on `merge`? Or better `combine_first`?

Comment: @piRSquared yep , already + for that , that is a great answer sir :-)

Answer (score 3):

Only if the indices are alligned (important note), we can use `update`:

```
df1['b'].update(df2['b'])


   a    b  e
0  1  0.0  a
1  2  1.0  1
2  3  0.0  2
3  4  1.0  b
```

Or simply `fillna`:

```
df1['b'].fillna(df2['b'], inplace=True)
```

If you're indices are not alligned, see [WenNYoBen's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56842215/9081267) answer or [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56842140/pandas-merge-and-fillna/56842231?noredirect=1#comment100236386_56842231) underneath.

Comment: `df1.set_index('a',inplace=True);
df1.update(df2.set_index('a'));
df1.reset_index()
`

Answer (score 2):

You can mask the data.

original data:

```
print(df)
   one  two  three
0    1  1.0    1.0
1    2  NaN    2.0
2    3  3.0    NaN

print(df2)
   one  two  three
0    4    4      4
1    4    2      4
2    4    4      3
```

See below, mask just fills based on condition.

```
# mask values where isna()
df1[['two','three']] = df1[['two','three']]\
        .mask(df1[['two','three']].isna(),df2[['two','three']])
```

output:

```
   one  two  three
0    1  1.0    1.0
1    2  2.0    2.0
2    3  3.0    3.0
```

Comment: Note how my example has 3 columns, so you have to merge somehow

Comment: I edited to account for this.  You can mask more than once column at a time.  No merge required.  Still requires the order to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

These answers didnt work for me in pandas 1.5.3, but by manipulating the suffixes a bit, I got this to work:

```
df1.fillna(df1.merge(df2, how="left", on="a", suffixes=["_old", ""]))
```

This results in this output:

```
    a   b   e
0   1   0.0 a
1   2   1.0 1
2   3   0.0 2
3   4   1.0 b
```