# Merge two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge two different dataframe which the second one has some rows to complete in the first one.

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['red','green','yellow','blue'],'b':[1,5,6,7],'c':[1,7,8,9]})
df5 = pd.DataFrame({'a':'red','b':44, 'c':55}, index=[0])
print(pd.merge(df4,df5, how='left', on='a'))
```

Output

```
     a    b_x   c_x  b_y    c_y
0   red     1   1   44.0    55.0
1   green   5   7   NaN NaN
2   yellow  6   8   NaN NaN
3   blue    7   9   NaN NaN
```

Expected Output

```
    a      b    c
0   red    44   55
1   green   5   7
2   yellow  6   8
3   blue    7   9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df4.update(df5)
```

Output:

```
>>> df4
        a     b     c
0     red  44.0  55.0
1   green     5     7
2  yellow     6     8
3    blue     7     9
```

Comment: There are no NaN values

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, @luka. I tried using your latest sample data, and this worked.

Comment: While this is in-place (modifies the existing df, and doesn't return a new df), I think this is what you're looking for. :)

Comment: yes I am sorry :)

Answer (score 3):

Replace `-` with `np.nan` and use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df4.replace('-',np.nan,inplace=True)
df4.combine_first(df5)
```

prints:

```
        a     b     c
0     red  44.0  55.0
1   green   5.0   7.0
2  yellow   6.0   8.0
3    blue   7.0   9.0
```

Comment: But how do you actually just use `merge` to do it? I'm puzzled.

Comment: @sophocles I edit the example, there is no way to use np.nan

Comment: if you want to use ```merge``` I believe you will have to use it with some other steps, so it won't be just a single merge. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56842140/pandas-merge-dataframes-with-shared-column-fillna-in-left-with-right) answer gives a detailed description on how you can use it. Why can't you use ```np.nan``` though?

Comment: @sophocles Because in my original problem, some values in the rows change between the two df

Answer (score 3):

Concatenate and drop duplicates by column 'a'.

```
print(pd.concat([df5, df4]).drop_duplicates(['a'], keep='first'))
```